# How can I hide field labels without using any CSS style?

Tags: 7, entities

How can I hide field labels from Drupal (without CSS)?

[image: http://s6.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/04/b35dca469a03a8827f5f3d0576e6f475.png]

---

```
function clean_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "user_register_form") {
    $form['account']['name']['#title'] = Null;
    $form['account']['name']['#description'] = Null;
    $form['account']['name']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('Имя пользователя'));

    $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = Null;
    $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = Null;
    $form['account']['mail']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => t('mail'));    
  }
}
```

I don't know how to write for password and date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to "Admin > Content Type > Manage Display" and hide the labels as shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i don't have manage display in my content type

Comment: "Manage display" does not apply to forms. Of course one could use hook_form_alter(). But I am also looking for a solution that does not require hard-coding of field names.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hide field labels in a node or nodes of one or more content types, and you want to do it conditionally, you can use `template_preprocess_page()` like so:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if($variables['node']->type == 'yourNodeType') {
        // hide what you wish here
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of page i must wrrite, if it is page--user--registation?

Answer (score 0):

just hide the label by going in content type->select the content type->manage display..then under the tag LABEL ,select hidden in tha select list options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 6 then the manage display link won't be visible.
then you need to manually alter the form using `form_id` and `hook_form_alter` by creating your custom module (The following code works in Drupal 7 too..).
For Ex.

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
     $form['password_field_name']['#title'] = NULL;
     $form['date_field_name']['#title'] = NULL;
   {
}
```

you need to first debug `$form_id` for which you need to alter the fields in your `mymodule_form_alter()` function and then debug the `$form` for your specific field names of `password_field_name` and `date_field_name`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't know field_id...it's devil log http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49611285/drupal_debug.txt

Comment: to get the field_id you need to login into drupal as administrator. 
Go to Administer > Content management > content types > Select your content type > manage fields. 

There you can see all fields of your content type. Out of that select your field and under **Operations** column just hover to configure link last argument you get will be **field_id**. 
For ex. http://test.com/admin/content/node-type/<your-content-type>/fields/<field_id>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default user register form then

```
$form['account']['pass']['#title'] = NULL;
```

If you have added manually by going into content-type then add this line in alter hook

```
$form['field_password'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#title'] = NULL;
```

['field_password'] will change according to you. EX : 
If you have created a field with name **Password** then it will have `'field_password'`

 Hope this will help you and other